# How can I debug a project from another solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I created a .NET solution 1 that consists of a project A and a project B. My solution also refers to a DLL only (project C) that is not included in my solution 1 but in a solution 2.

Sln 1 with project A and B with a reference to the DLL of project C
Sln 2 with project C

I would like to debug my C project from my solution 1. How can I do that without including the source code of my project C in my solution 1?

*In fact my project C is the framework of the my company and is developed by another team. I am able to get the source but not edit*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752211/debugging-dll-project-in-visual-studio-2008-using-attach-to-process

Comment: yes, that seems to be the right way. simply specify the soutrce code location for the modules and be sure to have the necesssary and matching PDB files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have Just My Code disabled (under Tools -> Options -> Debugging, called Enabled Just My Code), you can step into other libraries outside your solution and VS will prompt you to load the sources for it.  You can also open the source for C, set a breakpoint, and if the sources match the symbols, it should be able to stop at that breakpoint.